# AWS CLI S3 access with V2 signing

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I have a requirement to access data in an S3-compliant object store backed by DDN WOS. Due to particular circumstances I'm having trouble getting vendor support. The recommendation is to use s3tools/s3cmd (https://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to access the store. However, I'd prefer to use AWS CLI if possible.

The object store requires S3 V2 signing. AWS CLI uses the current signing (V4) by default. I don't see an AWS CLI configuration that directly supports V2 signing, but the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) describes the ability to specify an older API version using the `api_versions` configuration setting. I'm wondering if setting this to an older S3 API version might also use the older signing algorithm. (Just a hope, really.)

The AWS docs say "Refer to the documentation for each service to understand which API versions are available". Versions are specified in the form YYYY-MM-DD. The current S3 version is 2006-03-01 per documentation. So far, though, I've been unable to find a list of API versions for S3.

If anyone knows a) where is a list of S3 versions can be found or b) if it is possible to use AWS CLI with V2 signing, help is appreciated.

Comment: The S3 API has always remained backwards compatible, so the API version has never been bumped from `2006-03-01`. There isn't an older version Sig V2 and Sig V4 are both overlaid on that same API version, so if there is a way to force aws-cli to use V2, it is not related to API version.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html#specify-signature-version suggests that there's a way to force v4, so there's probably a way to force v2.  Check that?